# About float parameter transfer between function method

Tags: iphone

I have a function method in class file.
like this:

```
-(NSArray*)getPayMoney:(NSUInteger)money month:(NSInteger)month rates:(float)rates;
```

when I transfer the rates value 0.06 from this, in debug mode get rates is 0.059999.
Does anyone knows the reason?

Comment: If you are working with real money and want high precision then you should use `NSDecimalNumber`. We, as users, tend to get pissed when float precision causes us to lose money, even if it's just cents ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is fundamental Computer Science - floating point representation simply cannot represent all decimal numbers accurately. Please do some reading:

- [Floating Point: Accuracy Problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)

The bottom line: if you are working with currency values, do **not** use floating point types. You will have two major problems: first, you cannot always accurately convert currency values to floating point and back, and second, you could have rounding errors that give incorrect results in certain calculations.

You **must** use a BCD or decimal type to calculate with currency.  Apple provides direct support for this in Cocoa:

- [NSDecimalNumber Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)